# Any pins on rs232 which can be used to detect voltage as input

Tags: c#, serial-port

Is there a way i can get a voltage input using rs232? What i am doing now is i have 2 pc hooked up to rs232 to communicate using gnd, tx and rx pin. Ive also connect DTR to a switch and when the switch is pressed im able to get a voltage output to drive a LED. What i want to do now is that when the led lights up, i will somehow get a input and change some stuffs in m programming. Is it possible to do that? Thanks in advance.

P.S. Im doing C# programming

Comment: Typically "no".  That's the kind of situation where "DAQ" (Digital Acquisition Hardware) comes in to play, for example: Advantech, [National Instruments](http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/209145) or [TI](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/analog/dataconverters/data_converter.page?DCMP=hpa_bestbets&HQS=hpa-sc-bb-dchome)

Comment: Are you looking for a variable input i.e.(0 to 5) or are you looking for a 2 state input On/Off

Comment: Im just looking for On/Off. For example, if it is 5v ill do 1 thing. If its 0v ill do another. Thanks for all your response!

Comment: For this sort of question you might get better answers at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @chuawoohian are you using the SerialPort Class ? if so look at the [CTSHolding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.ctsholding) or the [DSRHolding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.dsrholding.aspx) Property's for reading the CTS or DSR pins.

Comment: Yes im using serial port class. Let say if i use CTS or DSR pin as input, will it mess up with the 2 PC sending and receiving data to each other?

Comment: RS232 can output +/-12Vdc, but some newer computers may use 5Vdc (TTL) instead. And there are usually protective resistors to limit current, so it may not be ideal for lighting LEDs

Comment: @chuawoohian I think it will depend on if you have handshaking enabled or not, I would play with it and see if it works, you can also try using CDHolding to check the CD input.

Comment: Thanks for all your response!

Answer (score 0):

Not directly.  Your port RS323 communicates using digital signals that are always 5 volts.  You need an analog-to-digital converter (ADC) between your voltage source and the RS232 port.  Check out sparkfun.com for plenty of options.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several inputs. First of all which are inputs depends on if the RS232 is a DCE or DTE. Originally this standard was put together to connect a terminal to a modem. The DCE is the model and the DTE is the terminal. You wire the pins 1 to 1. Hence Tx can be a receiver or a transmitter.

A PC is typically a DTE. With that in mind this info may make more sense now: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232

The voltages are a nominal +- 7V. Actual a typical range of +-3V to +-15V. Be warned on a negative voltage is a logic 1.

As for C# you have access to all of the pins. Check out the class SerialPort.

Good luck

Rob

Comment: Yes, you have access to the logic values (0 or 1) of all the pins.  But read voltage?  I don't think so...

Comment: @paulsm4 You can read On/Off which sounds like what he is wanting, not a variable voltage

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. I did it.

Just connect the - (minus, ground) of the energy source to RS232 RX pin (Refer to anywhere in Internet to be sure where the RX pin is). When you give voltage (as pulse) to this pin, you see some meaningless actions in your port. There appears an OnComm event as 'Receive' but it has no start bit, no stop bit, it is fully meaningless. But any program which monitors RS232 (COM Ports) will show that something is happening on the port (Such as ' 00 ' in HEX or '[00]' in ascii).

As I said it has no start and stop bits, its voltage is not the average voltage needed for RS232 communication, so you must detect it with a subroutine like this (you can not handle it any other way):

Create a timer with 1ms.

timer1.enabled = false
 ----Don't forget to disable it
 if mscomm1.inbuffercount > 0 then
  -----put your code here
  -----it means the voltage has appeared at RX
  -----for example you can code 'buttonpresscount=buttonpresscount+1'
 end if
waitfortheactionend:
 if mscomm1.inbuffercount >0 then
  ----there is still some meaningless voltage
  ----wait until pulse ends, so
  doevents
  goto waitfortheactionstop
 end if
 ----Don't forget to enable the timer again
 timer1.enabled = true

I hope this will be helpfull.
Sedat K.