# Detect serialport voltage

Tags: c#, vb.net

Is there any program in c# or vb.net that can detect the voltage from serial port? I've tried to use the pinchanged but it doesn't support my program, which is the windows form will hide if detected a voltage from serial port.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear (at least to me) from your question what exactly you mean.

The serial port is a digital device, it understands two levels: high and low (zero and one, or mark and space or whatever). Reading your question one gets the impression you want to read analog values from your serial port (a voltage that might take any value from say, 0 to 10 V). If that's what you mean I'm afraid it's not possible out of the box (you can do that with an Analog-to-Digital converter with a serial output, which should not be difficult to [find](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/data-converters/analog-to-digital-converters/MAX186EVKIT.html) or put together with an [ADC](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1085) plus a [converter](http://sandboxelectronics.com/?product=sc16is750-i2cspi-to-uart-bridge-module)).

On the other hand, if what you mean is to use your serial port as a digital input to detect high or low (digital) states, then you can try to use the [`SerialPinChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialpinchange?view=netframework-4.8) event on the Clear to Send (CTS) or Data Set Ready (DSR) signals.

Note that to be able to use DSR or CTS you need to either have a real (legacy) serial port (those with the SUB-D9 connector) or a USB adaptor that exposes those signals somewhere (most of them only have CTS, see for instance [here](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/serial-basic-hookup-guide/all)).

Related:

-Great Q&A on EESE: [how to use a serial port as digital output](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34326/use-uart-tx-as-digital-output).

-Similar question: [Any pins on rs232 which can be used to detect voltage as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606620/any-pins-on-rs232-which-can-be-used-to-detect-voltage-as-input) but not properly answered IMHO.